# Is it possible to disable "People" view in Hudson?

Tags: java, hudson

I would like to disable page "People" in Hudson. I don't want users to see other users. Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if you can do it directly with Hudson, but you certainly be able to do it if you run [Hudson within a Tomcat instance](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Tomcat) (I run mine in a Tomcat 7 without any problem).

You would define a JSP [security-constraint](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/realm-howto.html), a bit like [those ones](http://blog.mc-thias.org/?title=tomcat_ldap_authentication&more=1&c=1&tb=1&pb=1) (note: adapted for LDAP because I defer all user authentication to the webapp container of Hudson: in my case, Tomcat)

---

The OP asks:

> You're suggesting to make changes to `hudson/WEB-INF/web.xml`? Could you please explicitly mention the file I have to change?

@Vincenzo: I don't! I never touch one bit of the `hudson.jar`. I only use it within a Tomcat instance, meaning:

- I declare in `<tomcat>/conf/Catalina/localhost` a context for each Hudson I want to manage:

```
  hudson-xxx -> /home/me/context/hudson-xxx.xml
```

(it is a link because I want to upgrade Tomcat easily, so I externalize the context definition outside of Tomcat). I define my Realm for ACL purposes:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context docBase="/home/me/hudson/hudson.war" path="/hudson-xxx">
  <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.real.CombinedRealm" >
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.real.JNDIRealm" debug="99"
           connectionURL="ldap://xxxxx:389"
           alternateURL="ldap://xxxxx:389"
           connexionName="yyyy"
           connectionPassword="zzzz"
           userPattern="CN={0},OU=...,DC=..."
           userRoleName="memberOf"
           useSubtree="false"
           roleBase="OU=...,DC=..."
           roleName="cn"
           roleSearch="(member={0})"
           roleSubtree="false"
    />
  </Realm>
  <Environment name="HUDSON_XXX" value="/home/me/hudson/hudson-xxx-home" type="java.lang.String" override="false" />
</Context>
```

(With that context, a `hudson.war` stored outside of Tomcat is automatically deployed with the `</tomcat>/webapps` directory, and access from `http://tomcat-server/hudson-xxx`, with an LDAP-based authentication)

- **I suggests modifying the `</tomcat>/conf/web.xml`** to add security-constraint which would prevent anybody to access the user page while letting only certain tomcat users (as defined in **/conf/tomcat-users.xml**.
  (I haven't tested it yet)

Comment: You're suggesting to make changes to `hudson/WEB-INF/web.xml`? Could you please explicitly mention the file I have to change? Thanks

Comment: @Vincenzo: I have updated my answer with Tomcat-specific details.